# How to Insert Ads before the Paragraph

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add the ad before the paragraph. How can I do that?

This code is adding ads after the paragraph.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ads_after_paragraphs');
function ads_after_paragraphs( $content ) {

    $adsafterparagraph = array(1,5,10,15);

    global $post;

     $ad = 'ADS CODE';

    $content_expl = explode("</p>", $content);
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($content_expl); $i++ ) {
        if (in_array($i, $adsafterparagraph)){
            $content_expl[$i] = $content_expl[$i].$ad;
            }
    } 

    return implode("</p>", $content_expl);
}
```

Comment: Change `1,5,10,15` to `0,4,9,14` will probably do the trick, I'd think.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want this. I already use it. The ad is not good on some pages in the last paragraph.

Comment: I want to have some content after the ads..